# Dictionaries and keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is the question:

create a dictionary with values such as

```
(1: a, 2:b , 3:c 4:d)
```

Write a Python script to add a key to a dictionary.
Write a Python script to sort (ascending and descending) a dictionary by value.
Write a Python script to check if a given key already exists in a dictionary

```
dictionary = {
    "a":1,
    "b":2,
    "c":3,
    "d":4,
    "e":5,
    "f":6,
    "g":7,
    "h":8,
    "i":9,
    "j":10
    }
print (dictionary)
def is_key_present(x):
    if x in d:
        print ("key is present in the dictionary.")
    else:
        print ("key is not present in the dictionary.")
```

Comment: What is the question? I didn't find it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide us with your own solution for every sub-question. Then we will be able to give you suggestions, not answers to your HW.

Comment: 1)d[key] = value 2)  use ordered_dict, 3) if x in d, 0) fill: {k : v for v,k in enumerate("1234567890")}

Answer (score 0):

**First Question:**

```
import operator
dictionary = {
    "a": 3,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 1,
    "d": 4,
    "e": 5,
    "f": 6,
    "g": 7,
    "h": 8,
    "i": 9,
    "j": 10
}

sorted_asc = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print(sorted_asc)
```

**Second Question:**

```
def key_in(key, dic):
    rett = False
    if key in dic:
        rett = True
    return rett
```